# Send (POST) currently loaded HTML code to a locally hosted server

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I have a endpoint running on my local machine and I want to post the html src of any web-page I open in my browser to it.
I have written a chrome-extension, but the Content Security Policy doesn't allow me to use `fetch` api.

Is there way to specifically bypass CSP for a specific extension. I could modify the CSP before the page is loaded from my extension but this might be a security risk, If I were to distribute it to others, or use on a daily basis.

A workaround could be accessing the history stored on the native machine and then fetching every visited URL directly from my endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea in case you use Node.js on the endpoint.

Use [`puppeteer`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to connect to the browser via [DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) and monitor [event: `'targetcreated'`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-targetcreated) for new tab creation and [event: `'load'`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-load) for opened tabs navigation. Then you can get [`page.content()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagecontent) on each navigation.

Something like this:

1. Launch the browser as:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

2. Connect with this code:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
  browserURL: 'http://localhost:9222',
  defaultViewport: null,
});

try {
  browser.on('targetcreated', async (target) => {
    if (target.type() === 'page') {
      const page = await target.page();
      page.on('load', () => { getData(page); });
    }
  });

  const currentPages = await browser.pages();
  for (const page of currentPages) {
    page.on('load', () => { getData(page); });
  }

  async function getData(page) {
    console.log(await page.title());
  }

} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Currently the `'load'` event is fired twice for the sites without favicons, but this can be eliminated by using a simple URL filter with, for example, a URL history in a `Set`.

Comment: I am using go-lang on the endpoint. But I think I've found a similar package https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp . Ill also give this a try.